# Mostrar o valor real da porcentagem

Tags: php

Tenho um sistema onde ele tira a porcentagem do cálculo de 2 valores. Para isso estou usando a regra de 3.

```
$vTotal = ($pdProdutos->product_promotion_price / $pdProdutos->product_price) * 100.'%';
```

O problema está quando o resultado fica dessa forma:

```
$v1 = '5.50'; // $pdProdutos->product_promotion_price
$v2 = '7.50'; // $pdProdutos->product_price
$vTotal =  ($v1 / $v2) * 100;
echo $vTotal; // saída: 73.333333333333%
```

Se eu usar o `ceil()`, ele irá arredondar para mais, ou seja, 74%, o que não é a proposta, já que o desconto é de 73%. Como posso resolver isso no PHP? Pensei em usar dessa forma:

```
$vTotal =  ($v1 / $v2) * 100;
list($v,$r) = explode('.',$vTotal);
echo $v; // saída: 73%
```

Mas não sei se seria uma solução plausível para o problema. Existe alguma função nativa do PHP que me dê o resultado real do cálculo?

Comment: E se for 73,999 o resultado deve ser 73 ou 74? Dependendo do que vc precisa, pode usar `floor` ou `round`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem duas maneiras.

#### Exibir somente o valor inteiro

Se você quiser obter apenas o valor inteiro do seu cálculo, você pode fazer a conversão pra inteiro assim:

```
$vTotal = (int) (($v1 / $v2) * 100); // 73
```

Com certeza a solução acima é melhor só que usar o explode. Nunca é um bom caminho aplicar tratamentos de string em números.

#### Diminuindo as casas decimais

Caso você queira manter as casas decimais, você pode usar a função `round()` especificando quantas casas decimais deseja manter.

```
$vTotal =  ($v1 / $v2) * 100; // 73.333333...
$vTotal = round($vTotal, 2); // 73.33
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Wallace. Usei o primeiro exemplo `$vTotal = (int) (($v1 / $v2) * 100);`